# Opensea Metadata Line Break

Tags: opensea, meta-data

I'd like to add a line break to my NFT's description, but

`export const metadata = ["NFT Name", "Hi! \nThis is my NFT"];`

\n would straight up not show break and not show metadata. Without the line break, everything works fine.

How do I add a line break in a way that works?